# mosquitto MQTT broker set up - getting Connecting with MQTT server failed (NotAuthorized)

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

i'm trying to set up a broker on windows machine with Eclipse Mosquitto,
i followed all the steps based on this :

```
https://delightnet.nl/index.php/mqtt/12-mqtt-broker-installation
```

i have a listener i build in c# and i'm able to connect with it to another broker,
but when trying to connect to the broker i created, i'm getting
"MqttConnectingFailedException: Connecting with MQTT server failed (NotAuthorized)."
I Opened port 1883 in my firewall inbound and outbound.
Added this port in mosquitto.conf

my listener (working fine with another broker)
Console.WriteLine("Starting Subscriber....");

```
                //create subscriber client
                var factory = new MqttFactory();
                _client = factory.CreateMqttClient();

                //configure options
                _options = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                    .WithClientId("sOc/BB:93:16:DE:E3:CA/s")
                    .WithTcpServer("63.250.63.219", 1883).WithCredentials("myBroker", "myBrokerpass")
                    //.WithTcpServer("39.108.54.186", 1883).WithCredentials("gateways", "admin")
                    .WithCleanSession()
                    .Build();

                //Handlers
                _client.UseConnectedHandler(e =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected successfully with MQTT Brokers.");

                //Subscribe to topic
                _client.SubscribeAsync(new MqttTopicFilterBuilder().WithTopic("sOc/BB:93:16:DE:E3:CA/s").Build()).Wait();
                });
                _client.UseDisconnectedHandler(e =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from MQTT Brokers.");
                });
```

Comment: Edit the question to include your `mosquitto.conf` and the mosquitto log output that shows the failed connection attempt

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set up a broker, just go to https://mosquitto.org/download/ and install the package accordingly. **No need coding**.

If you want to test with the installed broker, you can use `mosquitto_pub` and `mosquitto_sub`. You can also use many client libraries for your client side coding.

Answer (score -1):

Solved.
changed allow anonymous from false to true in the mosquitto.conf

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, that just let's anybody connect.